# I have expected stock returns on US and globally ex-US. How do I combine them?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, percentage, weighted-mean, geometric-mean

Edit:
If US stocks are 56% of world stocks and they have a 5.09% expected return, while the other 44% have a 2.31% expected return, how do I calculate the expected return of world stocks, the 100%?

Should I combine them with a weighted arithmetic mean, weighted geometric mean or something else? What's the expected return of the 56/44 US/ex-US portfolio?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does it mean to combine them? A portfolio composed of 50/50 US and Ex-US stocks will have a different expected return than a 25/75 or 0/100 portfolio.

Comment: I added an edit to try to clarify. I want the expect return of the 56/44 US/ex-US portfolio.

Comment: Hi: you weight the returns by the universe weights.  So, 0.44 * 2.31 + 0.56 * 5.09.